excel 2021 crash while export files to pdf (batch)
I have about 200 xlsx files in folder and i need export them to pdf in batch.
In task manager i can see an increase of memory use (excel) from about 100 MB to about 850 MB and then excel crashes. It raises after each file is exported.
So I think i need free memory after each cycle or prevent prevent the used memory from increasing.
Processor is loaded at 3-30% use, Memory at 80-93%. (Task manager)
Excel crashes after export approx 160-170 files
I tried set the objects to nothing, but that didn't help.
I tried wait 2 sec after each file.
After adding wait time, Excel no longer crashes, but the memory (950 MB) remains occupied even long (minutes) after the macro is finished.
I expect more stable memory usage by Excel (and no crashes).
code for cycle files:
Sub se_TiskVsechSouboruVeSlozceDoPDF_2S()
' Print  all files in folder to PDF - prejmenuje soubory dle regionu a oblasti
' Primarne urceno pro tisk vyplnenych formularu
    
    Dim region As String
    Dim hlavickaDialogu As String
    
    Dim wb As Workbook

    hlavickaDialogu = " - Export formulářů do PDF"
    
    If cVlny1 = "" Then cVlny1 = f_cisloVlny(hlavickaDialogu)
        If ukoncit = True Then Exit Sub
        
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    fileDir = InputBox("Zadej cestu k souborům", "xxx - Tisk formulářů", "x:\yxz\" & CisloProjektu & "- xxx\" & CisloProjektu & "-" & cVlny2 & "\Precteno_All\")
      If fileDir = "" Then Exit Sub
            fileDir = Replace(fileDir & "\", "\\", "\") 'osetri zaverecne lomitko
            
    outputFileDir = "x:\SpojovaniRuby\" & rok & "-" & cVlny2 & "\"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FileSearch = "*"
      fileName = Dir(fileDir & FileSearch, vbDirectory)
        'Erase search_dir
          ReDim Preserve search_dir(1 To i)
            search_dir(1) = fileDir
            
              Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                ' create folder
                If Not fso.FolderExists(outputFileDir) Then MkDir (outputFileDir)
                
                  Do While fileName <> ""
                    
                      If fso.FolderExists(fileDir & fileName) And Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
                        i = i + 1
                          ReDim search_dir(1 To i)   ' puvodne bylo Redim Preserve
                            search_dir(i) = fileDir & fileName & "\"
                      End If
                        fileName = Dir()
                  Loop
                  Set fso = Nothing
 
    'search in given dir
    For i = 1 To UBound(search_dir)
      FileSearch = "*.xls*"
        fileName = Dir(search_dir(i) & FileSearch)
   
          Do While fileName <> ""
              If Left(fileName, 15) = "spojene_soubory" Or Left(fileName, 17) = "vysledek_kontroly" Or Mid(fileName, 9, 15) = "_chybový_report" Then GoTo Skok
                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=search_dir(i) & fileName)     'open file
                
                '---------------------  macro for file save     ----------------------------------------------------
                Call se_TISK_jednoho_souboru_do_PDF_2S(wb, outputFileDir)
                '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Skok:
            fileName = Dir()
            Set wb = Nothing
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
         Loop

    Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

and the code for the export itself:

'export one file to pdf
Sub se_TISK_jednoho_souboru_do_PDF_2S(wb As Workbook, outputFileDir As String)

   Dim region As String
   Dim oblast As String
   Dim nazevProdejny As String
   Dim nazevPDF As String
   Dim kodProdejny As String
   Dim hlavickaDialogu As String
   
    Dim listDatovy As String
    Dim listTiskovy As String
    
    'Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    listDatovy = "Formular"
    listTiskovy = "Tisk2S"
    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
  'Unlock sheets with given poassword
  Call de_Odemci_List_peku(wb)
        
       wb.CheckCompatibility = False       'vypne kontrolu kompatibility
       
          Set ws = wb.Sheets(listDatovy)
       
    'create variables for file name from file data | Tvorba nazvu souboru - data z formulare xxx
        region = Replace(ws.Range("AB4").Value, " ", "") & "_"
             oblast = Replace(ws.Range("AC4").Value, " ", "") & "_"
          
          kodProdejny = Left(ws.Range(bunkaNazevProdejny).Value, 3)
               nazevProdejny = Mid(de_Diakritika(ws.Range(bunkaNazevProdejny).Value), 5, 100)   'zruseni diakritiky a mezer
                 nazevProdejny = Replace(nazevProdejny, "--", "-")                        'zruseni dvojitych carek
                   nazevProdejny = Replace(nazevProdejny, "--", "-")                        'zruseni dvojitych carek
            
        ' file name of pdf
        nazevPDF = region & oblast & kodProdejny & "_" & nazevProdejny & "_dotaznik"
           nazevPDF = Replace(nazevPDF, "-_", "_")                             'zruseni techto carek
         
           'export to pdf
           Set ws = wb.Sheets(listTiskovy)
           
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
                  outputFileDir & nazevPDF & ".PDF" _
                      , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas _
                          :=False, from:=1, To:=11, OpenAfterPublish:=False
       
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=False                    'zavře soubor
          
          Set ws = Nothing
          Set wb = Nothing

End Sub



    Dim Region, oblast, NazevProdejny, NazevPDF, KodProdejny, hlavickaDialogu As String in this way only the last is a string, all the previous are Variant and may have something to do with the memory usage.
The first time you use searchdir there is no need to Preserve (nor to delete it, as it was never appearing earlier):
Erase search_dir: ReDim Preserve search_dir(1 To i) : search_dir(1) = fileDir

Thnaks Oran, i corrected variables definitions; commented  "Erase search_dir " line

When i commented "redim" line, code stopped at "subscript out of range" error. So I uncommented it and ran it. Same result. PS: fileDir, fileName, outputFileDir are Public strings.

What i meant is that Preserve  is not needed, as there is nothing to keep, You do have to ReDim .

Thanks Orlan, for improving my programming. However, this macro still needs a solution.

Move the line Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") before the start of the loop, since you only need to create the object once (not once for each file). Refactor Sub se_TISK_jednoho_souboru_do_PDF_2S() to take wb as an argument, so that you form an explicit link to your target workbook rather than the implicit link you get with just using ActiveWorkbook. Similarly, refactor de_Odemci_List_peku() also to take wb as an argument, for the same reason.

Thanks Spectral, I did it. Memory consumption is now about 50-100 MB less. Still about 800 MB.

What is the excel version you are using 32 or 64 bit. Excel 32 is not stable to my experience..

@Aldert, I use 64 bit Office.

Do you need the fso variable in your se_TISK_jednoho_souboru_do_PDF_2S() procedure - you're using it to create the outputFileDir directory if it doesn't exist but, since outputFileDir is wb.Path (which is already a pre-existing directory) so this test (and fso) is un-necessary?

Thanks @Spectral, I deleted fso definition and directory test. Memory consumption is reduced to approx. 750 MB. I don't know if this is a good value or not. (I think not). What if there are 300-1000 files? Is it normal for Excel?

Given the comments so far, and the changes you have made based on those, please edit your question to reflect your code as it currently exists (following your updates) - this will make analysing it more straightforward.

@Spectral, code edited.

In your main procedure se_TiskVsechSouboruVeSlozceDoPDF_2S()  you are finished with fso after the loop terminates so I think you should set it to Nothing before the line For i = 1 To UBound(search_dir) to release memory as soon as it can be released.

@Spectral, thanks, i did it. Code updated.
I noticed that Excel runs several (up to 10) instances of Microsoft Edge WebView2. Each consumes approx. 5-50 MB. Does anyone know what to do with it?

Sorry, I can't advise on that. At this stage, what I would suggest is dumping the content of search_dir to a worksheet, filter it for the 3 strings you want to avoid, and then save that net result in its own file. Then, you could work through that in batch sizes determined by your available memory.
